# TableView selected cells - checkmarks disappear when scrolled out of sight and new cell checked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7

I have a tableViewCell that uses a checkmark in `accessoryType` of cell. I have a function that puts the contents of the cell into textField and similarly removes the text from the text field when it is unchecked.

It seems to work fine but if I check a cell and want to check a cell thats not visible (IOW) I need to scroll the tableView, the cell that was checked (is now not visible) seems to uncheck itself (Only when I check a new visible cell).

The multi select works with visible cells only.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) 
    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = painArea[row] 
    cell.accessoryType = .None 
    return cell 
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //selectedRow = indexPath
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let row = indexPath.row
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        if cell!.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
            cell!.accessoryType = .None
        } else {
            cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }
    populateDescription()
    print(painArea[row])
}

var painDescription = ["very sore"]

func populateDescription() {
    painDescription.removeAll()
    severityText.text = ""
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
        if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
            painDescription.append((cell.textLabel?.text)! + " ")
        }
        var painArea = ""
        var i = 1

        while i <= painDescription.count {
            painArea += painDescription[i-1] + "~"
            i = i + 1
        }
        severityText.text = painArea

    }
```

I hope I am explaining myself adequately. I don't want the non visible cells to be unchecked and thus removed from my text field unless I uncheck it.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Kind regards

Wayne

Comment: please post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method..

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = painArea[row]
        cell.accessoryType = .None
        
        return cell
    }

Comment: add if-else condition in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method for checking cell have Checkmark or not. If Yes then add accesoryType .checkmark otherwise .none..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happing because of reusability of Cell. Instead of setting `Checkmark` in `didSelect` try to set in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Also you need to create `model` class like this to solve your problem

```
class ModelClass: NSObject {
    var isSelected: Bool = false
    //Declare other property that you are using cellForRowAtIndexPath
}
```

Now check this `isSelected` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) 
    let row = indexPath.row 
    let modelClass = painArea[row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = modelClass.name
    if modelClass.isSelected {
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
    }
    return cell 
}
```

Now change your didSelect like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var modelClass = painArea[indexPath.row]
    modelClass.isSelected = !modelClass.isSelected
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    populateDescription()
    print(painArea[row])
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because whenever u scroll the cell out of view and scroll back, it will call the `cellForRow` again and set everything back to default, what you have to do is create a properly dataSource, whenever a cell got checked, you update the dataSource with a Bool indicate it has been checked, then set it back in the `cellForRow` or `cellWillDisplay`

Comment: In my cellForRowAtIndexPath I had: accesoryType as .None. I have commented this out and it seems to work. @Dev.RK helped me by asking me to post my cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: That practice is only for keeping the UI, u should update your datasource, not the UI itself, the answer from Nirav show the basic on doing that