# On scroll UITableViewCell added button image issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableViewCell and added button left side of cell for check mark cell is selected or unselected.
Number of rows in uitableview 50.

Issue:
First row is selected and added the checkmark to button, then I scroll the UITableView, I found that another check mark is added to another cell.
Is any one face same issue, your input will be appreciated.

//Cell For Row IndexPath

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableCell];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:UITableViewCell owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.checkButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

// Image changes in Storyboard.

```
-(void)checkButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isSelected]) {

        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }
    else {
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38263787/6433023)

Comment: The cell in UITableView is reusing, so every time use a cell which may comes from reusing pool ,you should reset it to defaults status.

Comment: you can reset your cell in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.section`  or `tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`, as you like!

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question , its the cell being re-used by iOS sir. The line below is the culprit.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableCell];
```

What this does is look for an existing cell in the table view, and loads that cell.

You said, You clicked one cell and it had the checkmark, right?

Well, fortunately when you scroll away from it, the cell gets reused by the tableview by above call and is seen again in the list of visible cell with the checkmark.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableCell];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:UITableViewCell owner:self options:nil];
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.checkButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Looking at your calls in the above method, you never set the checkmark to either on or off, sir. You are reusing the cell that already had the checkmark. So, when you see it again, it also has the checkmark, because you never changed it anyway.

NOTE: IT'S NOT RANDOMLY GIVING CHECKMARKS.

AT THE BEGINNING, DON'T SCROLL. GIVE CHECKMARK TO ALL THE CELLS AND YOU WOULD GET YOUR ANSWER. NOW START SCROLLING. Every cells should have checkmarks now.

Solution:

To solve this issue, in your datamodel, add a isCheckmarkSelected:Bool property.
And, anytime user checks the cell, make isCheckmarkSelected to true.

In the method call, [ cellForRowAtIndexPath ]... read the isCheckmarkSelected value and set the checkmark of the cell.

This would solve the not so random checkmarks issue.

Kind Regards,
Suman Adhikari

Answer (score 0):

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814060/check-uncheck-buttons-in-uitableviews-cell)
This above link is worked fine for my question.
in button action add extra code `[[self.tableview] reloadData];`